# InvalidCastException from StateServer session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state, .net, stateserver

A site I've written is experiencing a strange issue whereby it suddenly doesn't recognize items stored in the session immediately after I've made any update to the code.  I've searched Stackoverflow / google / etc and can see that some other people have the same problem but can't find a solution anywhere.

Here's roughly what's happening:

If I add an item to my basket it stores a `List<BasketItem>` in the session.  If I then make an update to some code (not BasketItem) the session variable still exists but .NET doesn't seem to think the it's a `List<BasketItem>` even though it definately is.

When I try and retrieve the list of basket items after modifying the code it throws an `InvalidCastException` which just doesn't make any sense as it's basically trying to say the types it's converting between are different even though they are not.

The exception is:

> System.InvalidCastException:
>   [A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BasketItem] cannot be cast to
>   [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BasketItem]. Type A originates
>   from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at
>   location
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at
>   location
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.

I'm using StateServer for the session state and running ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 if that helps.

The code I'm using is below:

```
// for setting the basket
List<BasketItem> basketItems = new List<BasketItem>();
Session["basket"] = basketItems;

// for getting the basket
List<BasketItem> basketItems = (List<BasketItem>)Session["basket"];
```

For the moment I'm using 'as casting' so I doesn't error but it does mean user's basket's are being lost when the code is updated.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Tim

Comment: I wonder if this relates to two different BasketItem types; can you confirm: is it possible that this is loading when *saved* from 1 build version, then *loaded* from a different build version? Is BasketItem perhaps coming from 2 different assemblies? Is it possible you have different machines in the same farm with different build versions, or maybe each machine is building independently?

Comment: (it is somewhat annoying that the error message tells us about the `List<>` instead of `BasketItem`, making it hard to see if the string would tell us something obvious)

Comment: Hi mark, regarding your first comment - yes I suppose .NET could be loading BasketItem from two different assemblies.  Whenever there are changes to the App_Code I think .NET recompiles it into a new assembly.

Comment: that'll do it, for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *type* of problem is pretty common due to how `BinaryFormatter` stores the underlying type data, which can cause problems if that they doesn't resolve to **exactly** the same `BasketItem` that you had in mind. Most frequently, this hurts when changing the version of your application / library, or when there are different servers with different states.

My **strong advice** here is: don't let it use `BinaryFormatter` to store the state! It is **not** very version friendly, in both this regard and a few other issues *within* a type. If it is possible, I urge you to consider strong *contract-based* data instead (meaning: virtually anything other than `BinaryFormatter` / `NetDataContractSerializer`). Examples:

- you could use `JavaScriptSerializer` and store a basic `string` of the data
- you could use `XmlSerializer` and store a basic `string` of the data
- if you want binary, you could use protobuf-net and strore a `byte[]` of the data

You would obviously then use helper methods to store/retrieve your data, normally with a generic `void Store<T>(string key, T object)` and `T Retreive<T>(string key)`, using `typeof(T)` internally as-necessary. The advantage of this is that the stored data is now neutral of any particular implementation, and can be consumed by other versions of your application (since nothing is type-dependent), and even by other platforms (Java, php, etc) if necessary.

I appreciate this is a side-step *around* the problem rather than a direct solution - but: it works.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  I like your suggestion about serializing the BasketItem class to Xml and storing that as a string in the session.  I can't see that .NET would have any problems with that so I'm definately going to try it!